# Is it possible to record video of a Java Swing Component?

Tags: java, swing, video

I am looking for a way to make a video out of a java JComponent.  I found ways to save components as images, but ideally I would like to be able to have the component paint to the screen and to a video file.  I am hoping to find a solution that does not require libraries outside of the core JDK, but lightweight libraries might be considered.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there are libraries that will do what you are asking.  Indeed, it seems a rather strange approach.  Could you explain what it is that you are trying to achieve.

I suspect that a more viable approach is to use a screen video capture tool like [Camtasia](http://www.techsmith.com/camtasia.asp) to capture what the user is doing.  It costs money, but they do have an evaluation download if your boss is a cheapskate.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response.  I have a java applet with a java component that displays an animation with the Piccolo2D library.  I want to allow the user to record the output of that Piccolo2d component.  Having the user install a 3rd party application is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The core Java JDK doesn't provide a way to write videos, but you can create videos from raw images using the [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) open-source project.  See this [source code](http://wiki.xuggle.com/MediaTool_Introduction#How_To_Take_Snapshots_Of_Your_Desktop) for examples of creating a video from raw images that are snapshots of a desktop.

- Art