# From rendering 2D Java to Flash

Tags: java, video

Is there a way to render 2d graphics to flash.  And if not directly to flash, is there a way to render 2d graphics to a some video format in Java?

Ideally, I don't want to do motion capture the swing application, I want to use the Java libraries to render the video.

The graphics might include something simple, a colored rectangle moving across the screen.

What are the key technologies for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the image to JPEG using `ImageIO`, then `JpegImagesToMovie.java` of the JMF can transform those images to MOV format.

Comment: @Ben: The source would have to be edited to accept JPEG images from memory, but yes, it can be done.  BTW - congrats. on earning (half) the bounty.  ;)

Answer (score 5):

In answer to a [similar earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943763/is-it-possible-to-record-video-of-a-java-swing-component) [Xuggler](http://wiki.xuggle.com/) was mentioned as a way of encoding video from a sequence of images. I haven't seen anything in Java to actually capture graphics as a video stream.

I've just found the [QuickTimeWriter](http://www.randelshofer.ch/cubetwister/javadoc/ch/randelshofer/media/quicktime/QuickTimeWriter.html) class used in Werner Randelshofer's [CubeTwister](http://www.randelshofer.ch/cubetwister/index.html) application. The example code in the Javadoc doesn't quite work out of the box, but I did manage to hack together some code to generate a movie from one of my existing Swing demo applications by "printing" my JComponent to a BufferedImage at regular intervals. There may be a better way but it works as a proof of principle.

You should check the conditions if reusing the code, but if I understand correctly he is making the it available under a [Creative Commons Attribution](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/) licence.